# Who wrote the acrostics that appear at the beginning of Plautus's plays?

Tags: plautus

Almost every Plautus play that I have read begins with an acrostic that lays out the *argumentum*. Here's an example from the *Menaechmi*:

> Mercator Siculus, quoi erant gemini filii,
>   Ei surrupto altero mors optigit.
>   Nomen surrepticii illi indit qui domist
>   Avos paternus, facit Maenaechmum e Sosicle.
>   Et is germanum, postquam adolevit, quaeritat
>   Circum omnis oras. post Epidamnum devenit:
>   Hic fuerat alitus ille surrepticius.
>   Menaechmum omnes civem credunt advenam
>   Eumque appellant meretrix, uxor et socer.
>   I se cognoscunt fratres postremo invicem.

I have even noticed some plays, like the *Mercator*, that have two.

**Did Plautus write these acrostics?** If not, who did and how do we know? Do we know if they were used in the performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have no idea who wrote the argumenta for Plautus' plays.

[Fontaine 1996](https://books.google.com/books?id=SFPUvjlSUIsC&pg=PA254#v=onepage&q&f=false) notes:

> The acrostic *argumentum* prefixed to *Gorgylio* that spells out CURCULIO suggests that the paradigm [of Latin names for characters] had shifted in antiquity. However, because **we do not know when these acrostic *argumenta* were written** and because it remains possible that ancient readers interpreted *Curculio* as an authentic, archaic transliteration of *Γοργυλίων*, its evidentiary value is limited.

[Hammond, Mack, Moskalew](https://books.google.com/books?id=FREobG0sEnUC&&pg=PA22#v=onepage&q&f=false) suggest that they were scholars in the second century:

> Furthermore, scholars, probably during the second century A.D., composed brief summaries of the plots, called *argumenta*, in imacic seenarii. There survive for all the comedies of Plautus, except for the incomplete *Bacchides* and *Vidularia*, summaries the first letters of whose lines spell the names of the plays concerned, that is, acrostic summaries. For seven plays of Plautus...there are also non-acrostic summaries, as there are for all those of Terence.

They [go on](https://books.google.com/books?id=FREobG0sEnUC&&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> [Non-acrostic] ones for the plays of Terence are attributed to a scholar of the Hadrianic period, Sulpicius Apollinaris. [...] As the notes will indicate, **the summaries show words and meaning characteristic of Silver Latin**.

There's a very old hypothesis (at least as early as Wheeley's collection of Ben Jonson's works in 1756) that Priscian the Grammarian (5th/6th century CE) was its author. This is unlikely. One, it's attribution to Priscian is just a guess, included by "[some editors](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ab8DAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA59&#v=onepage&q&f=false)" (though I'm not sure who was the first to do so). Moreover, the idea that acrostics are "late" is wrong, and acrostics have been used at least as early as [Aratus' *Phaenomena*](http://www.persee.fr/doc/rea_0035-2004_1960_num_62_1_3638).

As Hammond, Mack, Moskalew above point out, the Latin is better located in the first couple centuries CE. Even as early as [Smith's *Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aA9QAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA409#v=onepage&q&f=false) do we find doubt based on style and word choice that Priscian could have written it.